# locate/run ios6 simulator in XCode 5.0

Tags: xcode, simulator

I realize this must be user error, but I can't find how to start the ios6 simulator via XCode 5.0.  I have the latest version installed and checking components tells me the ios6 & ios5 simulators are up to date.
Thanks.
More info:
WIthin the simular, I see only ios 7 & ios 5.1 offered.  Additionally, within XCode, I can't find the usual option for choosing the ios version at the top left of application.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote. XCode is frequently flakey. Also, sometimes people miss obvious features.  In this case, I can't find my mistake. I don't know if its an XCode problem or mine, and I'm just looking for a little assistance - which just might help others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ***Install iOS-Simulator6.0 in XCode5 components:***[image]
- ***You can find the the option to choose iOS simulator version as below:***[image]

Comment: Caught by the new simple graphics/transparency paradigm!  The download arrow beside the simulators, plus the fact that XCode was indicating everything was installed, looked (to me) as if it was indicating that all the simulators were installed too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the ios simulator go to Hardware>Device>iphone> ios6.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the option for ios 6 isn't there.  I see only ios 7 & ios 5.1.  Additionally, I can't find the usual option for choosing the ios version at the top left of XCode.

Comment: This is what your simulator should look like [screenshot](http://puu.sh/4zgYK). If it is not looks like this then go to Xcode>preferences>downloads and download the ios 6 simulator from components section.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't figure out why that wasn't available.  Turns out the download button on the components screen looked like a plus (indicating installed) to me. Thanks for your assistance.